# How to console.log arabic text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log, cpu-word

I want to output this word(دریا) but at console.log the output is: %D8%AF%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7
But it must be : 'دریا'
can anyone help me

```js
console.log("دریا")
```

Comment: Seems to work just fine here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-gagarin-gptb2 Your question is tagged with node.js. Are you logging this in node.js? Given that the value looks like it is URL-escaped, I suspect there is more to the story. Show us your code.

Comment: yes in nodejs. The problem is when I find the text that I paste from Google strange . I got the word sea from Google and it became %D8%AF%D8%B1%DB%8C%D8%A7

Comment: maybe you're using a poorly made web-based terminal emulator, because it seems to work fine in node.js on my machine

Comment: Thats just urlEncoded version of that string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with console.log :

```js
console.log("دریا");
```

I get the same result (as above) when trying this in node.js. It succeeds.

Based on your comments, perhaps you are copying text from a source that isn't [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded? For example, if the webpage (you're copying text from) is `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`, instead of `<meta charset="UTF-8">`, your clipboard may be receiving an encoded form of the arabic characters you're expecting to be able to paste.

As a test, try copying characters from [here](https://www.key-shortcut.com/en/writing-systems/%EF%BA%95%EF%BA%8F%D8%A2-arabic-alphabet), to see if you get a better result with `console.log()`; that page is encoded in UTF-8. If this works, and yet your other source doesn't, maybe the source is the problem. To get characters from that source, you may have to decode them first.

Comment: The string the OP posted is Hex bytes for utf-8. `D8 AF` corresponds to code point `(U+062F)` which is the Arabic letter Dal `د`. `D8 B1` is code point `(U+ 0631)` Arabic Reh, etc. It's not clear how the op is getting bytes like this, but the bytes are UTF-8.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Nice details. How did you acquire them?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking — converting between code points and hex is described well here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 and a nice source of encodings is here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-8/list.htm?start=1024

Comment: @MarkMeyer Looks like I need to read my own linked references above. Thanks for both links.